# Какие коды состояния HTTP может возвращать PHP-скрипт помимо тех что были указаны явно?

Tags: php, http

Допустим в скрипте явно описаны 200 и 404 коды ответов. Какие ещё коды ответов может вернуть PHP-скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых все коды состояния возвращает не php а сервер, во вторых научитесь [гуглить](http://www.restapitutorial.ru/httpstatuscodes.html)
все 500 коды как правило ошибки выполнения скрипта(в вашем случае php) на сервере

Comment: Хорошо, тогда какие ответы возвращает скрипт веб серверу?